# Api 21 Circular Reveal Animation not working

Tags: android, animation, android-5.0-lollipop

I can't get the circular reveal animation to work.
I think I checked the most obvious things:
It starts, width and height are > 0 and it is visible, no Exception..

I load some data from the internet and display it in the view(fab)
The animation should only play after the download finishes.

```
TmdbHelper helper = new TmdbHelper();
                helper.getMovieById(id, "en", new TmdbHelper.ResultListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResultReceived(JSONObject result) {

                        // called when finished downloading

                        try {
                            String rating = result.getString("vote_average");

                            AnimationHelper.circularReveal(fab, 500, 0); 

                            fab.setText(rating);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                });
```

AnimationHelper:

```
    public static void circularReveal(final View view, final long duration, long startDelay) {

    // get the center for the clipping circle
    int cx = (view.getLeft() + view.getRight()) / 2;
    int cy = (view.getTop() + view.getBottom()) / 2;

    // get the final radius for the clipping circle
    int finalRadius = Math.max(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());

    // create the animator for this view (the start radius is zero)
    Animator anim =
            ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(view, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);

    anim.setDuration(duration);
    anim.setStartDelay(startDelay);

    anim.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
    });

    // make the view visible and start the animation

    anim.start();
}
```

I use the circular reveal animation in other parts like this to make sure the view is attached, and it works:

```
headerContainer.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    headerContainer.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    AnimationHelper.circularReveal(headerContainer, 500, 200);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should erase this line inside your `onResultRecieved()`:

```
fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

My assumption is that your circular reveal method is working just fine. It is because of you have made the FAB visible before the animation even begin, you can't see it in action.

As an addition, those lines you've shown which is working doesn't have `fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` called anywhere in it.

Comment: I just added it afterwards, it doesn't work without also...
Just forgot to remove it again
Btw: It is set as "invisible" in the xml

Comment: Well then I'm out of ideas.. But since you mentioned that the code works everywhere else, it can't be the reveal's fault. Are you sure `onResultRecieved()` is being called?

Comment: Yes it is. The Button appears, with the data I set in onResultReceived, but without animation...

Comment: You forgot to start the animator. Also, depending on how it is placed, you may be running into the location problem. The animator's center is relative to the view, so you should use getWidth()/2 and getHeight()/2 for the center.

Comment: @GeorgeMount That last sentence should be better documented. Especially since https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Reveal incorrectly uses int cx = (myView.getLeft() + myView.getRight()) / 2; instead of int cx = myView.getWidth() / 2

Comment: Yes, I have fixed the documentation internally, but I suspect that it won't go out until M is released.

Answer (score 0):

1st Approach:
Try Transition Listener.

```
                getWindow().getSharedElementExitTransition().addListener(new Transition.TransitionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTransitionStart(Transition transition) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTransitionCancel(Transition transition) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTransitionPause(Transition transition) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTransitionResume(Transition transition) {

                    }
                });
```

2nd Approach: Try setting start delay and listener to the reveal animation and when animation starts then set the view visible

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(viewRoot, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);
        anim.setStartDelay(300);
        anim.setDuration(1000);
        anim.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        anim.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                viewRoot.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

            }
        });
        anim.start();
    }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

            }
        });
        anim.start();
```